# User not able to edit a Lotus form

Tags: lotus-notes, acl, lotus-domino

A user is not able to edit a form. The user had editor access and i've tried to replicate the issue using a test user and providing the same access as the user, but to no avail. I came across a link which told me that there is something called as additional ACL control in Lotus Administrator. I'm not sure if this actually can influence the editing privileges. I don't think that could be the problem. Anyway, please let me know if you can figure out the problem. 
Additional info:
The user is a part of a distribution list(multipurpose group) and the group has editor access. 
The default access to the form is Author, with a authors field in the form. 
The user has 2 names mentioned in the names.nsf person document. An old name and a new name.
The required user roles are assigned to the group.

Let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: @KenPespisa response is the normal way to go. Is the db hosted on a server? If so use DEBUG_SERVER_ACL=2 . Then post the debug for the user in your question. IMPORTANT! Remove anything that may look confidential from the log. Also remove the debug setting after the test as it is very verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Editor rights she should be able to edit. Please check her rights by placing a *Computed Text* with [@UserAccess](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WHATISUSERACCESS.html) on the form.

Or if she is using a Notes client she can simply click the "Security" icon in the bottom toolbar of the Notes, near the right corner. It will open a dialog box telling what is her access level to the database.

Comment: Yes, that's there in my checklist, i shall check it on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to check:

- is the user listed explicitly in the ACL?  If so, those rights will take precedence over any groups she's in.
- check the authors field carefully.  Best option is to look at the properties of the doc she's editing via the Notes client and examine the authors field in the dialog.  That will let you see if any code altered the list of allowed authors.  If she's an editor this shouldn't matter but based on the behavior you are seeing it sounds like she's acting as an author.

Comment: The user has not been given any access rights explicitly. She a part of a group with editor access. I agree that her access behaves like an authors access but i'm not able to figure out how. I'll try adding the user explicitly with editor access, but that wouldn't answer the question as to why is the user not able to edit otherwise.

Comment: What's the -Default- level in the ACL?

Comment: I've also sometimes had back luck when a group name was listed in the Authors field on a document and the user was not in the group when the document was created. It made no sense, but it did happen. Roles never had that problem, so I always use Roles in Author or Reader Names fields when I want groups to have that access.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the names in the authors fields are being stored in the canonical format and are not abbreviated or in common name. EG: using `Herny Newberry/MyOrg` does not work while using `CN=Henry Newberry/O=MyOrg` does.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. There was some problem with the user configuration. Thats the reason she was getting author access even though she was an editor. After reconfiguration of her Notes client, she'd able to edit the form now. Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered and a solution found, it should be noted that user-names listed in the 'fullname' field of the NAB person record should list the current or 'newname' first as other names may not be recognized.